# Flutter - Text inside LinearProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter i have **[LinearProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html)**. Works but i want to add a text (progression) INSIDE this bar.

I try something like this

```
SafeArea(
  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
  Center(
    child: Text(DateFormat.ms()
                .format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                 minuteSecond * 1000))
                 .toString())),
           Expanded(
             child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                     semanticsLabel: (animation.value * 100.0).toStringAsFixed(1).toString(),                
                     semanticsValue:  (animation.value * 100.0).toStringAsFixed(1).toString(),   
                     value: animation.value,
                     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                     valueColor:
                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red))),
])),
```

But obviously this add the text in the same line of the bar,  but not inside.

So: Somebody know how can i add the center (centered) inside this bar? Using *stack* element?

**UPDATE**

Anybody know how can i align vertically text inside ProgressBar?

[image: Not center]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to use `Stack`, try this:

For simplicity I hardcoded `0.6` value, you can use your `animation.value` in it.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: 0.6,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
      ),
    ),
    Align(child: Text("Text"), alignment: Alignment.topCenter,),
  ],
)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: And how can i align center vertically? Image that LinearProgressIndicator have a heigth 30. The text appear in top of bar. I Try 'alignment: Alignment.center' but doesn´t work.

Comment: Happy to help, please update your post with the current code you have and I'll be able to assist you better.

Comment: Cool, I added a separate answer just to keep things simple!

Answer (score 2):

use it like that, i increased the height of progress indicator cuz text doesnt fit.

```
       Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 18,
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Some Text'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: It's better to use `Align` instead of `Positioned` and `Center`

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your updated post:

[image]

---

```
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox.expand(
        child: LinearProgressIndicator(
          value: 0.9,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
      Center(child: Text("Timeout of phase communications")),
    ],
  ),
)
```